# Binary words that match in at least one position

Tags: combinatorics

How can i prove that 2 binary words (consisting of 0's and 1's) with the same odd length and the same number of 0's and 1's match in at least one position?

I think that pigeonhole principle can solve this but I don't see it so clearly

Thanks

Comment: Since there are an odd number of digits, one must appear more than the other...

Answer (score 2):

Sum of the differences is the difference of the sums:
$$(a_1-b_1) + \dotsb + (a_n-b_n) = (a_1+\dotsb + a_n) - (b_1+\dotsb +b_n) = 0.$$
If there were no match, then the former would be a sum of an odd number of $\pm 1$, hence odd.